# subtract old string from new one android

Tags: android

Here is the code for calculating **total bandwidth consumption** (value updates and increases every second). However, i want it to calculate the **network speed** which could be achieved by subtracting previous value from new one every second. How do i achieve that?

```
public class Browser extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private long mStartRX = 0;
    private long mStartTX = 0;

    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            calculate();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        //
        mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED
                || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
            alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
            alert.show();

        } else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

        }
        //
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        // Loading Spinner and status
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            findViewById(R.id.pb3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.pb3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };

    public void reload(View view) { // Reload Button
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

        TextView RX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RX);
        TextView TX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TX);
        TX.setText(TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + "");
        RX.setText(TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets() + "");
        android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
        mWebView.reload();
    }

    private void calculate() {
        TextView RX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RX);
        TextView TX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TX);
        // long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mStartRX;
        // RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
        long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mStartRX;
        RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes) + " bytes");
        if (rxBytes >= 1024) {
            // KB or more
            long rxKb = rxBytes / 1024;
            RX.setText(Long.toString(rxKb) + " KBs");
            if (rxKb >= 1024) {
                // MB or more
                long rxMB = rxKb / 1024;
                RX.setText(Long.toString(rxMB) + " MBs");
                if (rxMB >= 1024) {
                    // GB or more
                    long rxGB = rxMB / 1024;
                    RX.setText(Long.toString(rxGB));
                }// rxMB>1024
            }// rxKb > 1024
        }// rxBytes>=1024

        // long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - mStartTX;
        // TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
        long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - mStartTX;
        TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes) + " bytes");
        if (txBytes >= 1024) {
            // KB or more
            long txKb = txBytes / 1024;
            TX.setText(Long.toString(txKb) + " KBs");
            if (txKb >= 1024) {
                // MB or more
                long txMB = txKb / 1024;
                TX.setText(Long.toString(txMB) + " MBs");
                if (txMB >= 1024) {
                    // GB or more
                    long txGB = txMB / 1024;
                    TX.setText(Long.toString(txGB));
                }// rxMB>1024
            }// rxKb > 1024
        }// rxBytes>=1024

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Advanced.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0); // 0 for no animation
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create global variable and refer it instead of  parsing text?

Comment: could you provide a snippet? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Two global variable to store last received data.

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    //private long mStartRX = 0;
    //private long mStartTX = 0;
    private long mLastRX = 0;//Store Last RX data
    private long mLastTX = 0;//Store Last TX data

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tv_remote);


        mLastRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes(); //Set initial RX data
        mLastTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes(); //Set initial TX data
        if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED
                || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
            alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
            alert.show();

        } else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

        }
        //
    }


    private void calculate() {
        long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes(); // Latest RX data
        long rxSpeed = rxBytes - mLastRX; // Diff = Latest RX data - Last RX Data
        Log.i("TAG", "Speed RX:"+rxSpeed);
        mLastRX = rxBytes; //Set last RX data as Current RX data
        RX.setText(Long.toString(rxSpeed) + " bytes");
        if (rxSpeed >= 1024) {
            // KB or more
            long rxKb = rxSpeed / 1024;
            RX.setText(Long.toString(rxKb) + " KBs");
            if (rxKb >= 1024) {
                // MB or more
                long rxMB = rxKb / 1024;
                RX.setText(Long.toString(rxMB) + " MBs");
                if (rxMB >= 1024) {
                    // GB or more
                    long rxGB = rxMB / 1024;
                    RX.setText(Long.toString(rxGB));
                }// rxMB>1024
            }// rxKb > 1024
        }// rxSpeed>=1024

        long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes(); // Latest TX data
        long txSpeed = txBytes - mLastTX; // Diff = Latest TX data - Last TX Data
        mLastTX = txBytes; //Set last TX data as Current TX data
        Log.i("TAG", "Speed TX:"+txSpeed);
        TX.setText(Long.toString(txSpeed) + " bytes");
        if (txSpeed >= 1024) {
            // KB or more
            long txKb = txSpeed / 1024;
            TX.setText(Long.toString(txKb) + " KBs");
            if (txKb >= 1024) {
                // MB or more
                long txMB = txKb / 1024;
                TX.setText(Long.toString(txMB) + " MBs");
                if (txMB >= 1024) {
                    // GB or more
                    long txGB = txMB / 1024;
                    TX.setText(Long.toString(txGB));
                }// rxMB>1024
            }// rxKb > 1024
        }// rxSpeed>=1024

    }

}
```

Comment: @pleaseMOM let me know if you have any difficulties in understanding above code. I have removed few code and display on things that are needed. You can use other code if you needed.